# Android: Is there a way to get the size of a RemoteViews object?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

In my app widget, I have a LinearLayout whose height and width are set to fill_parent. Is there a way to get at runtime, the actual size that has been allocated to this view?

Answer (score 2):

The app widget meta data XML file determines the overall size of your widget; you must design your layouts with that size in mind.  If you are implementing multiple size widgets, you will need a separate meta data and layout for each one.

The app widget system uses an abstract "grid units" that you can turn into DP, see [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#anatomy_determining_size) for details.  If you set the size incorrectly, it will just "truncate" to the nearest grid size on your behalf (and your layout will look "bad").

Android 3 and 4 give you more possibility for sizing.